# Unable to Send email to external domains using C# Code from SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I am sending an email from Share Point server, i am using C# to send an email. 
For internal email addresses  i can send an email but when i use any other domain such as gmail ID , i am getting the below error.
 "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay"

I am using exchange as relay , so i try to send an email using powershell with a same settings (Port , mail server, username and password) to external and internal users , email is working fine . 
but using C# code from the same server i am getting error

"Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay"

```js
var mailserver = "mail.xyz.com";
        int port = "25";
        var senderemail = "abc@xyz.com";
        var senderpassword = "password";

        var client = new SmtpClient(mailserver.ToString(), port)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderemail.ToString(), senderpassword.ToString()),
            EnableSsl = false
        };
        client.Send(senderemail.ToString(), txtEmail.Text.Trim(), "Feed Back ", txtDesc.Text.Trim());
```